What if a modification to the main embodiment contradicts some of the general statements?
Throughout the specifications of the patent application, general teachings or details are given about the general idea of the invention.
However, a specific modification of the main embodiment later on in the application, because it is modified, contradicts some aspects of the general teachings.
Is this OK?

This is why you often see soft language, like "the widget 10 may have a bore 12". That may allows you to give an embodiment where it doesn't without enablement issues. However, if you say "its essential that the widget 10 has a bore 12..." and then later, the spec you say "in some embodiments, the widget 10 does not have the bore 12...", then you may run into enablement issues. Ideally you would say something like "As shown, a widget 10a is constructed in accordance with the widget 10, with the exception that the widget 10a does not include the bore 12." Since 10a is a "new" part, its enabled.

You might google “patent profanity”. It is a colorful way to bring attention to the dangers of certain words and expressions. One word people are highly advised to avoid is “invention”.
If the specification says “the invention has an X” the examiner can insist that every claim have that limitation and, alternatively, a judge can read that limitation into claims that do not even mention X.
We say “some embodiments of this teaching have an X” or the like.  I had my MS Word set to screamingly highlight any attempt to type “invention.”

Also, there was the recent issue of the heading "Summary of the Invention" having the OG claims paragraphs. Through prosecution, language was changed in the claims but the court limited the claims based on the text of the "Summary of the Invention" section.
